# Excel - Plotting different y-values on top of same x-values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I'm trying to figure out a way to plot my data so that values in the same category are stacked on top of each other like this:

[image: What I want]

But whenever I go to plot it I end up with this:

[image: What I get but do not want...]

I've been searching for similar questions but end up finding much more complicated problems I don't understand.

Comment: What type of graph did you select?  One problem I can spot is your first column.  Don't include that in your data selection for the chart.

Comment: I used a scatter plot. With or without the first column selected, I end up with the exact same graph in the picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably a few ways to do this.  Here's one.  I didn't have ready access to Excel, so I did this in LO Calc.  The menus are a little different, but I'll describe it.  Without a lot of customizing, I produced the basic chart:

[image: chart]

Here are the key steps.

- A chart type that treats X values as categories will see apples and bananas as labels, not category names.  Even though you have multiples of the same name, each entry will be plotted as a separate sequential value on the X axis, corresponding to item 1, item 2, etc.

  So I used a scatter chart.  I added a column of X values, using 1 for apple and 2 for banana to force the values to the right position on the X axis.
- I selected columns A and C of the data to create the graph, and selected the scatter chart (XY chart) type, with just points.  That gets you the points aligned the way you want.
- Now you need to deal with getting the X axis to look the way you want.  Select the X axis and go to Format Axis (you can right-click on the axis and it's a context menu item).
- Use the scale settings to control the min, max, and grid intervals.  For this example, I used min = 0, max = 2, major interval = 1, minor interval = 0.  You can play with these values to position the data on the graph.
- For the labels, I just selected no axis labels and added an axis title.  Then I entered Apples and Bananas, and played with the leading spacing and the spacing between them to get the alignment.  You could also use text boxes for the labels.

Comment: This was a perfect solution, thank you very very much!